# Trouble opening ports in SQL Server 2019 Express - WMI Error [0x80071779]

Tags: networking, sql-server

#### Update:

Going back one version to SQL Server 2017 Express allowed me to save TCP/IP ports and IP addresses entered in SQL Server Configuration Manager.

None of these variables were saved in the registry:
`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server**INST**\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\Tcp}\`

In SQL Server Configuration Manager this error message only appeared when an IP section had it's "Active" state set to "no":
`The specificed file is read only. [0x80071779].`

For me this applies to both 2017 and 2019.

---

#### Old description:

I Have installed a local SQL Server 2019 Express **(SSE 2019)**, that I can connect to locally with:
`<computer_name>/<sql_server_name>`.

I have issues trying to setup static ports to enable a remote connection.

When configuring ports in SQL Server Configuration Manager **(SSCM)** -> TCP/IP, upon saving I get a WMI error:
`The specificed file is read only. [0x80071779].`

Searching for the issue lead me to this [page](https://www.arcticdba.se/file-is-read-only-when-trying-to-change-tcp-settings-in-sql-server-configuration-manager/) that shows the same error message that I get.

This page describes a workaround by changing the ports and IP settings in the registry instead. However all the sub-keys to TCP: IP1, IP2, IP3 etc. are missing for me. Could someone running a SQL server 2019 express confirm that this structure is still in use for this version of SSE?

It's strange that the WMI error points to a read only issue when I am able to change the TcpPort value in the key called Tcp with SSCM (where it's called IPALL) and by restarting the server the value in registry is updated correctly.
`

#### So far my attempts to connect remote have failed

I have:

- Opened the standard SQL server port both in my router and my firewall
- Tried to turn off the firewall completely
- Added the keys missing and their contents in the registry [based on this](https://i1.wp.com/www.arcticdba.se/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/fel2.png), but did not seem to work (SSCM didn't even read from them)
- Restarted the SQL server and it's services, SQL Server Configuration Manager application and the computer several times while trying the above
- Made sure that remote connection is on in SQL server properties (was on by default)

---

### Some remarks about Connecting locally

#### Update:

When using only one instance of Sql server (and with working port management) you only need to enter the servers IP-address to initiate a connection.

---

#### Old:

While this went just fine:
`<computer_name>/<sql_server_name>`

I was unable to connect to the SQL server locally using `127.0.0.1` or `127.0.0.1, <port>`.
What's the correct syntax for connecting to the localhost?

Some suggestions were to use a comma to separate IP and Port:
`<x.x.x.x>/<SQL_server_name>, <PortNumber>`

Would it work just as well using a colon?
`<x.x.x.x>:<portNumber>/<SQL_server_name>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalled Sql server completely and installed a one version older sql server.
Setting it up the same way and the issue was solved. Updated the question as well.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (SQL Server 2019) none of the above was effective. The problem was related with Hyper-V. I suspect that the network bridge it creates conflicts with the SQL Server network settings. Uninstalling Hyper-V restores normal functioning. It could be possible that just deactivating the Hyper-V network bridge also work.